# How to replace parts of character cells in a list of dataframes in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, replace, conditional-statements

I have a list "L" of dataframes that looks like this (there are more than 2 dataframes in reality):

```
> L

[[1]]
                VAR
1 "Ab", "B", "C", "Dd", 

[[2]]
               VAR
1 "Ee", "B", "Ab", "H",
```

I.e. each dataframe contains one variable called "VAR" with one observation that consists of a list of characters. I'm looking for a way to replace all characters that satisfy a given condition with a number. In the example above, I would like to replace all "Ab"s with the number 5 and all "B"s with the number 3. How can this be done so that it applies to every dataframe (i.e. all "A"s) in the list "L"? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `chartr`

```
lapply(L, function(x) transform(x, VAR = chartr('A', '5', VAR)))
#[[1]]
#         VAR
#1 5, B, C, D

#[[2]]
#         VAR
#1 E, F, 5, H
```

#### Update

We can use `gsub` to match word that starts with 'A' followed by zero or more non-white space character (`\\S*`) and replace it with 5.

```
lapply(L1, function(x) transform(x, VAR = gsub("\\bA\\S*", 5, VAR)))
```

If we are looking for an exact match, then replace `A\\S*` with `\\bAb\\b`

```
 lapply(L1, function(x) transform(x, VAR = gsub("\\bAb\\b", 5, VAR)))
```

#### data

```
L <- list(data.frame(VAR = "A, B, C, D", stringsAsFactors=FALSE),
      data.frame(VAR = "E, F, A, H", stringsAsFactors=FALSE))

L1 <- list(data.frame(VAR = "Ab, B, C, D", stringsAsFactors=FALSE),
      data.frame(VAR = "E, F, Ab, H", stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
L <- list(data.frame(VAR = c("Ab", "B", "C", "D"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE),
          data.frame(VAR = c("E", "F", "Ab", "H"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
```

you could also use `purrr` and `replace`

```
purrr::map(L,  ~replace(.x,.x=="Ab",5))
```